# Problems upgrading to oscar 2

Tags: django, django-oscar

I am trying to upgrade from oscar 1.6.7 to 2.0

I have a few forked apps and have followed the instructions [here](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.4/releases/v2.0.html#migrating-forked-apps). i.e. renaming config.py to apps.py etc.

I get, however, an error and the apps don't seem to be loading correctly. Any ideas on how to approach debugging this? Thanks!

Below the full exception stack trace:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oscar/core/loading.py", line 228, in get_model
    return apps.get_model(app_label, model_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 193, in get_model
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 132, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./source/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/srv/source/apps/oscar/basket/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from oscar.apps.basket.abstract_models import AbstractBasket
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oscar/apps/basket/abstract_models.py", line 20, in <module>
    LineOfferConsumer = get_class('basket.utils', 'LineOfferConsumer')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oscar/core/loading.py", line 31, in get_class
    return get_classes(module_label, [classname], module_prefix)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oscar/core/loading.py", line 41, in get_classes
    return class_loader(module_label, classnames, module_prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oscar/core/loading.py", line 99, in default_class_loader
    oscar_module = _import_module(oscar_module_label, classnames)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oscar/core/loading.py", line 133, in _import_module
    return __import__(module_label, fromlist=classnames)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oscar/apps/basket/utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    ConditionalOffer = get_class('offer.models', 'ConditionalOffer')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oscar/core/loading.py", line 31, in get_class
    return get_classes(module_label, [classname], module_prefix)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oscar/core/loading.py", line 41, in get_classes
    return class_loader(module_label, classnames, module_prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oscar/core/loading.py", line 99, in default_class_loader
    oscar_module = _import_module(oscar_module_label, classnames)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oscar/core/loading.py", line 133, in _import_module
    return __import__(module_label, fromlist=classnames)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oscar/apps/offer/models.py", line 60, in <module>
    from oscar.apps.offer.benefits import *  # noqa isort:skip
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oscar/apps/offer/benefits.py", line 9, in <module>
    Benefit = get_model('offer', 'Benefit')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oscar/core/loading.py", line 240, in get_model
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, MODELS_MODULE_NAME))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/srv/source/apps/oscar/offer/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    class Condition(AbstractCondition):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 319, in __new__
    new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 224, in register_model
    (model_name, app_label, app_models[model_name], model))
RuntimeError: Conflicting 'condition' models in application 'offer': <class 'oscar.apps.offer.models.Condition'> and <class 'apps.oscar.offer.models.Condition'>.
```

The relevant INSTALLED_APPS:

```py
THIRD_PARTY_APPS += [
    "oscar",
    "apps.oscar.checkout",
    "apps.oscar.address",
    "apps.oscar.shipping",
    "apps.oscar.catalogue",
    "apps.oscar.partner",
    "apps.oscar.basket",
    "apps.oscar.offer",
    "apps.oscar.order",
    "oscar.apps.analytics",
    "oscar.apps.payment",
    "oscar.apps.catalogue.reviews",
    "oscar.apps.customer",
    "oscar.apps.search",
    "oscar.apps.voucher",
    "oscar.apps.wishlists",
    "oscar.apps.dashboard",
    "oscar.apps.dashboard.reports",
    "oscar.apps.dashboard.users",
    "oscar.apps.dashboard.orders",
    "oscar.apps.dashboard.partners",
    "oscar.apps.dashboard.pages",
    "oscar.apps.dashboard.ranges",
    "oscar.apps.dashboard.reviews",
    "oscar.apps.dashboard.vouchers",
    "oscar.apps.dashboard.communications",
    "oscar.apps.dashboard.shipping",
    "apps.oscar.dashboard.catalogue",
    "apps.oscar.dashboard.offers",
# This is a  djangocms website, so the following app is dealing with urls
    "apps.djangocms_oscar"
# It is a fork of this: https://github.com/maikhoepfel/djangocms-oscar
]
```

... and below offer/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.query import Q

from oscar.apps.offer.abstract_models import AbstractRange, AbstractCondition
from oscar.core.loading import get_model, get_class


class Condition(AbstractCondition):
    """
    Override condition to make it possibile that it will only be applied
    when only products of the selected range are in the basket
    """

    basket_in_range = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name="Reiner Warenkorb",
        default=False,
        blank=True,
        help_text="Nur anwenden, wenn Warenkorb ausschl. aus Sortiment besteht.",
    )


class Range(AbstractRange):

    def all_products(self):
        """
        Return a queryset containing all the products in the range
        This includes included_products plus the products contained in the
        included classes and categories, minus the products in
        excluded_products.
        """
        if self.proxy:
            return self.proxy.all_products()

        Product = get_model("catalogue", "Product")
        if self.includes_all_products:
            # Filter out child products
            return Product.browsable.all()

        return (
            Product.objects.filter(
                Q(id__in=self._included_product_ids())
                | Q(product_class_id__in=self._class_ids())
                | Q(productcategory__category_id__in=self._category_ids())
            )
            .exclude(id__in=self._excluded_product_ids())
            .distinct()
        )


from oscar.apps.offer.models import *  # noqa
```

Below offer/apps.py:

```
from oscar.apps.offer import apps


class OfferConfig(apps.OfferConfig):
    name = "apps.oscar.offer"
```

... and `offer/__init__.py`:
`default_app_config = "apps.oscar.offer.apps.OfferConfig"`

Comment: Please show us your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. It looks like you have got both Oscar's offer app and your forked app in there, which would cause this problem. If you for the app you need to *replace* it's entry in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: @solarissmoke Thanks for your reply, I updated with the relevant INSTALLED_APPS entries

Comment: Can you also show us the `models.py` of your forked offer app?

Comment: @solarissmoke Updated the post again

Comment: (Sorry - keep asking for more because I don't see an issue with anything you've posted so far). Please show us the app config class for your forked offer app.

Comment: @solarissmoke No problem, updated again. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, also, I think the second part of the trace may be a red herring, in that that exception occurs after the "Apps not loaded". I think the most likely issue is that something in your code is attempting to load models too early, and this is breaking the class loader. The stack trace doesn't provide the information required to identify where, but the likely places to look are in your URL configuration (make sure no models being loaded at module level).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217319/discussion-between-user2135738-and-solarissmoke).